# Wildfly with Spring Boot app: concurrent requests from SPA app result in 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, undertow

We deploy a Spring Boot app in Wildfly 18, through a war in an ear (using SpringBootServletInitializer). Other wars are present in the ear and session sharing is enabled. The wars also share a security domain.

Querying the Spring Boot app REST API from the browser or postman works fine. When it's a SPA app it fails: the concurrent requests get a 403 Forbidden, for example in the access log:

```
127.0.0.1 [02/Jul/2020:22:54:46 +0200] "GET /api/Foo?bar=1 HTTP/1.1" 403 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Serializing the SPA requests made it work again, but this was just for testing purpose: we want concurrent requests from the SPA!

I tried many configurations in the standalone.xml, for example this because we use session sharing and i wanted to have more than one request per session at a time:

```
     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:9.0">
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <locking isolation="NONE"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
```

or this to have undertow allow concurrent request:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0" statistics-enabled="true">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" max-connections="100" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="5000" allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <access-log pattern="%h %t &quot;%r&quot; %s &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot;" use-server-log="false"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-frame-options"/>
                <filter-ref name="limit-connections"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="UTF-8" max-sessions="10000">
            <jsp-config/>
            <session-cookie http-only="true"/>
        </servlet-container>
        <filters>
            <request-limit name="limit-connections" max-concurrent-requests="3000" queue-size="100"/>
            <response-header name="x-frame-options" header-name="X-Frame-Options" header-value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

Any help on getting rid of these nasty 403 on concurrent requests welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: the front app, in a war in the ear, wasn't in a security domain. And the default security domain isn't the one used by the other wars.

We have put the front war in the same domain (through the jboss-web.xml) and ... no more 403! We're a bit surprised the 403 wasn't on each call but then we're glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to permit [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) with SPA hosting server.

You can setup it by [Java Configuration(`WebMvcConfigurer`)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors-global-java) or [`@CrossOrigin` annotaion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors-controller).

Comment: thanks a lot
however all wars are in the same ear so on the same domain. 
On top most of the requests go through nicely, just some return 403 (and even then the session is still valid server side in fact, even if the front app thinks the user is logged out)